# Ghostscript: get CMYK values for rendering from PDF

Tags: c#, colors, ghostscript, cmyk

I need to get the CMYK values used for rendering from the PDF.

I think they are the values range 0 - 1.0 under the C1 key.

Does anyone know how to get them ?

Answer (score 2):

The CMYK values are nothing to do with the 'C1' key. There *may* be a colorspace defined as /C1, but it will not contain CMYK values.

Any object may be defined in a variety of colour spaces (Gray, RGB, CMYK, sRGB, Separation, DeviceN, NChannel, ICC and some special spaces), for those spaces which are not a device space (ie not Gray, RGB or CMYK) the colour is first converted into one of the device spaces. There are then rules defined in the PDF reference on how the device spaces are converted between themselves.

The actual colour components of an object will be defined in the content stream of the object (for vector objects in a page or Form context) or in the binary data (for images), or calculated from a function (Shading dictionaries).

In order to find any of these you will need to read the PDF file, decompressing streams as required, locate the object you want the information for and then determine the current colour space. Then you can convert the colour components from whatever colour space the object is defined in into CMYK.

Perhaps if you explained what your actual goal is it might be possible to be more helpful.

[UPDATE]

You could simply use Ghostscript to create a new, Grayscale, PDF by setting ColorConversionStrategy=Gray.

This has the advantage of working with all elements of the PDF not only images.

You do realise that a PDF file does not normally consist solely of a raster image ? There can be text, linework, shadings, and transparency groups can also be defined as operating in a given colour space. This is not a simple task.

If you are really only dealing with images then the ColorSpace is defined in the image dictionary (it may be an indirect reference). You will have to parse the PDF file (potentially decompressing it) to find the Color space definition. The sample values for each component are then given by the image data. These will range from 0-65535 (depending on the BPC, 1, 2, 4, 8 or 16 in the image dictionary) and you will have to apply the Decode array to map the values into a range suitable for the colour space.

If you then want to convert to gray scale, then you will have to apply a conversion to Gray. Complex spaces will include a method to map to a device space, and the conversion between device spaces is covered in the PDF reference manual. For ICCBased spaces you will need an ICC colour management engine, you might like to consider LCMS, or you could write your own.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have a PDF which has a colorspace defined in it which I need to convert to  a Gray Scale PDF. I am extracting the image from the PDF - than convert each pixel to Luminance and than create a new PDF with the converted image. This works fine for B&W pdf, but if there is a colorspace defined - the image is than rendered into the defined color (For Example - Magenta) so a Pure black rendered to a Pure Magenta. I know how to retrieve these values need to know how to factor them in my color conversion to Gray Sacel

Comment: You could simply use Ghostscript to create a new Grayscale PDF by setting ColorConversionStrategy=Gray. This has the advantage of working with all elements of the PDF not only images. You do realise that a PDF file does not normally consist of a raster image ?

Comment: Hi KenS, I continued exploring the issue and came out with the same solution as you suggest. I mannaged to have GhostScript save it's page to Gray Tiff file. Now, what I see is that what was supposed to be translated to a Pure Black Color - RGB (0,0,0) was translated to a dark gray RGB (102,102,102) - So now this is exactly my problem... How do I translate this value to be a oure black if I know the ColorSpace used for the PDF the page came from?

Comment: Ghostscript will not alter a pure black to such a different value of Gray. Its time for you to post an example so it can be examined. There is a pretty major section of documentation regarding colour management in Ghostscript, and if you want to get specific results you are going to need to read it. But in this case, I doubt that this is truly the conversion happening. For one thing if you convert to gray scale, the colour values won't be triplets (RGB) they will be single bytes.

Comment: Here is my code: **GhostscriptVersionInfo _lastInstalled = new GhostscriptVersionInfo(new System.Version(0, 0, 0), @"gsdll64.dll", string.Empty, GhostscriptLicense.GPL); List<string> switches = new List<string>(); switches.Add("gs"); switches.Add("-dSAFER"); switches.Add("-dBATCH"); switches.Add("-dNOPAUSE"); switches.Add("-dNOPAUSE"); switches.Add("-sDEVICE=tiffgray"); switches.Add("-r300"); switches.Add("-sProcessColorModel=DeviceGray"); switches.Add("-sOutputFile=figure.tif"); switches.Add(file);**

Comment: To run it I am using this code: **GhostscriptProcessor proc = new GhostscriptProcessor(_lastInstalled);          proc.StartProcessing(switches.ToArray(), null);** And with this PDF file: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/6qgypoafjv0kchj/AAD6b3q2OTuqVlTkXbD4TEFda?dl=0

Comment: You need to quote me a Ghostscript command line, I can't make sense of what you've posted. The file is 100% magenta, and yes, that does not map to 100% black. When you convert coloured data to gray scale it maps all the colours, except those specified in black ink, to a shade of grey. If it didn't then most colours would come out pure black which would make it hard to see. It would be best to use a simpler test file too.

Comment: gs -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=tiffgray -dOverrideICC -r300 -sProcessColorModel=DeviceGray -sOutputFile=figure.tif <Your Input File Here>

Comment: OK so I was assuming you were using pdfwrite, not creating a TIFF. I have to say I cannot see a problem, the gray scale representation looks reasonable to me. Given that the source isn't in RGB, and the destination isn't in RGB, I can't see what the actual problem is.

Comment: Given that you say you have to convert the PDF to gray scale, why are you rendering to TIFF ? I suggested you use the pdfwrite device and the ColorConversionStrategy to create a new, gray, PDF file.

Comment: Hi, Again thank you for your time. My end goal is to have the same PDF file diluted. The reason is to have it printed with less (lower layer) ink. By diluted I mean running over the image and reduce each gray level value according to a pre-determined table of values. So the problem begin when the image I extract is toned down to begin with ,,,

Comment: It seems to me your best bet is to render to a grayscale bitmap, manipulate the gray values, then print the bitmap. As an alternative, you can substitute a different set of ICC profiles in Ghostscript, which can be used to control the conversion into DeviceGray. Trying to do this yourself will be a large task. For starters you will need to be able to fully interpret the PDF file.